# Can you port forward with an android device

Tags: android, networking

I currently have my galaxy nexus tethered to my computer via wifi tether for root users, and I was wondering if there was a way for my to port forward either on the android device itself or through my PC running windows 7 and Ubuntu Linux. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ADB does have a port forward command](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#forwardports), see:

```
adb forward tcp:6100 tcp:7100
```

Although a little more clarification to your question may help in finding a solution for you.

Comment: Hi I am using my android hotspot on my Ubuntu laptop and I have a web app deployed on a local server listening on port 8080. Problem is I am not able to access the web app from the internet unless I connect the laptop with a USB Modem. How do I port forward so that my web app can be accessed from `http://ip-address:8080/my_web_app`?

Comment: Apparently, you cant do this anymore with a real device. You need to be root even if you have usb debugging. Its a shame. I get the idea of security, but if I really am a developer, it does nothing but make my life harder.